# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS xRDP keeps killing existing remote sessions

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm using my home Windows 11 laptop's built in RDP client to connect to my office Ubuntu workstation running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS through the xRDP server. 90% of the time, the client connects to the existing xRDP session and I can continue my work where I left off. However, 10% of the time, when I connect to the workstation, xRDP seems to kill the existing session and log in to a new one. I suspect so because I have a code that outputs timed logs every two seconds and when I get logged in to a new session, I see that my log from the previous session stopped just before I am logged in to the new one.

As I can already log in to existing sessions, tweaking the xRDP parameters to allow log in to existing sessions should be unnecessary. However, I don't understand why xRDP is killing the existing session that was running fine before it logs me in to a new one.

Any idea what is causing the issue and if there is a good way to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using the**Gnome Remote Desktop** or `xrdp server`? The 2 with differently.

Comment: I'm using xRDP server